# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 216.58.212.106:443

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created windows service using C# to extract lowest fare data from Google QPX Express. The program is working on debug mode but when I install on my machine it is raising *No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused*. Here is the code which I have inserted in the App.Config file.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True"  bypassonlocal="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue using the below config.

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
<proxy usesystemdefault="True"  bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://server:port" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

and also configure the service to run on local system account, provide the username and password after you install the service